# Why does GCC use frame pointer when I call Win32 functions with arguments?

Tags: gcc, x86, stack, frame, stdcall

When I compile 32-bit C code with GCC and the -fomit-frame-pointer option, the frame pointer (ebp) is not used unless my function calls Windows API functions with stdcall and atleast one parameter.

For example, if I only use GetCommandLine() from the Windows API, which has no parameters/arguments, GCC will omit the frame pointer and use ebp for other things, speeding up the code and not having that useless prologue.

But the moment I call a stdcall Win32 function that accepts at least one argument, GCC completely ignores the -fomit-frame-pointer and uses the frame pointer anyway, and the code is worse in inspection as it can't use ebp for general purpose things. Not to mention I find the frame pointer quite pointless. I mean, I want to compile for release and distribution, why should I care about debugging? (if I want to debug I'll just use a debug build instead after reproducing the bug)

My stack most certainly does NOT contain dynamic allocation like alloca. So, the stack has a defined structure yet GCC chooses the dumb method despite my options? Is there something I'm missing to force it to not use frame pointer?

My second grip I have with it is that it refuses to use "push" instructions for Win32 functions. Every other compiler I tried, they used push instructions to push on the stack, resulting in much better more compact code, not to mention it is the most natural way to push arguments for stdcall. Yet GCC stubbornly uses "mov" instructions to move in each spot, manually, at offsets relative to esp because it needs to keep the stack pointer completely static. stdcall is made to be easy on the caller, and yet GCC completely misses the point of stdcall since it generates this crappy code when interfacing with it. What's worse, since the stack pointer is static, it still uses a frame pointer? Just why?

I tried -mpush-args, it doesn't do anything.

I also noticed that if I make my stack big enough for it to exceed a page (4096 bytes), GCC will add a prologue with a function that does nothing but "bitwise or" the stack every 4096 bytes with zero (which does nothing). I assume it's for touching the stack and automatically commiting memory with page faults if the stack was reserved? Unfortunately, it does this even if I set the initial commit of the stack (not reserve) to high enough to hold my stack, not to mention this shouldn't even be needed in the first place. Redundant code at its best.

Are these bugs in GCC? Or something I'm missing in options? Should I use something else? Please tell me if I'm missing some options.

I seriously hope I won't have to make an inline asm macro just to call stdcall functions and use push instructions (and this will avoid frame pointer too I guess). That sounds really overkill for something so basic that should be in compilers of today. And yes I use GCC 4.8.1 so not an ancient version.

As extra question, is it possible to force GCC to not save registers on the stack at function prologue? I use my own direct entry point with -nostartfiles argument, because it is a pure Windows application and it works just fine without standard lib startup. If I use **attribute**((noreturn)), it will discard the epilogue restoring the registers but it will still push them on the stack at prologue, I don't know if there's a way to force it to not save registers for this entry point function. Either way not a big deal in the least, it would just feel more complete I guess. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the answer [Force GCC to push arguments on the stack before calling function (using PUSH instruction)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618009/force-gcc-to-push-arguments-on-the-stack-before-calling-function-using-push-ins)

I.e. try `-mpush-args -mno-accumulate-outgoing-args`. It may also require `-mno-stack-arg-probe` if gcc complains.

Comment: I have updated GCC to 4.9.0 and it seems not only this works, but the frame pointer is also not used anymore at all. Maybe it was a bug in 4.8.1. Solved now, thanks, hope it helps someone else also.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like supplying the -mpush-args -mno-accumulate-outgoing-args -mno-stack-arg-probe works, specifically the last one. Now the code is cleaner and more normal like other compilers, and it uses PUSH for arguments, even makes it easier to track in OllyDbg this way.

Unfortunately, this FORCES the stupid frame pointer to be used, even in small functions that absolutely do not need it at all. Seriously is there a way to absolutely force GCC to disable the frame pointer?!