# Why Is GCC Using Mov Instead Of Push In Function Calls?

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, x86-64, stack-memory

So I've got this example C program.

```
int worship(long john)
{
    return 0 * john;
}

int main()
{
    return worship(666);
}
```

The assembly looks (essentially) like this:

```
worship(long):
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    ret
main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movl    $666, %edi
    call    worship(long)
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

I ran into this while reading about stack smashing. In the assembly `worship(long):` section where it says `movq   %rdi, -8(%rbp)` I would expect it to be using `pushq` based on everything I've read so far. Is this the new way that GCC is pushing arguments onto the stack and if so is there a compiler flag I could be using to toggle this?

Comment: oh, maybe that's an optimization. as far as i know movq doesn't change the value of stack pointer

Comment: What? it is a very common and basic function frame...

Comment: in x86_64 the number of registers has been double, so the [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions) uses registers for the first parameters, not stack

Comment: I think it gives more space for optimizations. If you have a sequence of two function calls differing only by the second argument, you can simply change this argument while keeping the first on the top of the stack. And of course you do not need to adjust SP when returning from functions.

Comment: Poss duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534791/why-does-it-use-the-movl-instead-of-push

Comment: It is a basic code optimization.  The PUSH instruction is awkward because it makes *two* modifications, it writes to [ESP] *and* modifies the ESP register.  This prevents out-of-order execution, a problem that MOV doesn't have.

Comment: @harmic, yes it would appear so. It even looks like he's reading the same article on buffer overflows as I am.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, I thought it might be skipping the stack so I tried a case with a bunch of arguments to worship() and it behaved the same but I didn't realize there were twice as many registers in x86_64.

Comment: why do you think that `movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)` is a parameter pushing? Any parameters must be inputted from the calling function, which is `main` here. The callee must read out the transferred parameter

Comment: if you're using Linux then the first 6 integer parameters are passed in RDI, RSI, RDX, RCX, R8, and R9. So that's why there's RDI in the function. Pass 6 parameters and you'll see that it uses R8 and R9, which is one of the new registers. Try passing more than 7 parameters and then the stack will be used

Comment: In my defence of this repost thing, the original answer is very vaguely titled

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[GCC manual](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Flinux.die.net%2Fman%2F1%2Fgcc&ei=9ekaU7uqIceErge7r4D4Cw&usg=AFQjCNHpK9ENjeXYlNcH9K6BA7AT87fpWw&bvm=bv.62578216,d.bmk) says,

```
-mpush-args
```

> Push instructions will be used to pass outgoing arguments when functions are called. Enabled by default.

```
-mno-push-args
```

> Use PUSH operations to store outgoing parameters. This method is shorter and usually
>       equally fast as method using SUB/MOV operations and is enabled by default. 
>       In some cases disabling it may improve performance because of improved scheduling
>       and reduced dependencies.

```
-maccumulate-outgoing-args
```

> If enabled, the maximum amount of space required for outgoing arguments will be computed in the function prologue. This is faster on most modern CPUs because of reduced dependencies, improved scheduling and reduced stack usage when preferred stack boundary is not equal to 2. The drawback is a notable increase in code size. This switch implies -mno-push-args.

Even `-mpush-args` enabled by default it is override by `-maccumulate-outgoing-args` which is enabled by default. Compiling passing option `-mno-accumulate-outgoing-args` explicitly could change the instructions to `push`.

Comment: **This is the right answer to a different question, about how GCC would pass stack args (e.g. in 32-bit code)**.  x86-64 System V passes the first 6 integer args in registers RDI, RSI, RDX, RCX, R8, R9.  No combination of these options will change the `movl    $666, %edi` in `main` to pass the arg to the callee.  And *spilling* the register arg to `-8(%rbp)` (in the red zone below RSP) is also not arg *passing*, it's just [a consequence of a debug build (`-O0`)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53366394).  Doing *that* using `push` wouldn't be a win here, because it can use the red zone.

Answer (score 1):

x86-64 System V passes the first 6 integer args in registers RDI, RSI, RDX, RCX, R8, R9.  So in `main` we have `mov $666, %edi` (which zero-extends to the full RDI) to **pass** the 64-bit arg `long john`.

`push` can't write registers; nothing<sup>1</sup> can stop GCC from using `mov` to set registers, and you wouldn't want to.  If you passed 7 or more args, GCC normally would use `push` in `main` to pass the 7th on the stack, because `-mno-accumulate-outgoing-args` is the default in modern GCC.  `push` has been efficient on x86 since Pentium-M or so introduced a "stack engine" to track stack-pointer updates specially.

[Sunil Bojanapally's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267767/why-is-gcc-using-mov-instead-of-push-in-function-calls/22267930#22267930) covers those options, which are more relevant for 32-bit code where all args are passed on the stack.  If you got here from searching on the title question, see that answer or *[Why does gcc use movl instead of push to pass function args?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534791/why-does-gcc-use-movl-instead-of-push-to-pass-function-args)*  This answer is about the actual question, which is about what the callee does with its incoming arg in a debug build, not about how the arg is passed to it.

---

**You're talking about the code inside the callee that stores that incoming arg to the stack**.  This isn't *passing* an arg, it's just [a consequence of a debug build](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53366394) - every C variable gets a memory address unless declared `register` with the default `-O0` anti-optimization level.  Compilers emit instructions to store incoming register args to the stack.

In this case `movq %rdi, -8(%rbp)` is storing to the [red zone](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/red-zone/info) below RSP, since `worship()` is a leaf function.  The stack space is already effectively reserved (down to `-128(%rsp)`, and at this point RBP=RSP).

And just to be clear, **this is not part of the function *call***.  [Spilling incoming args to the stack inside the callee only happens in a debug build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51976465/why-does-the-x86-64-system-v-calling-convention-pass-args-in-registers-instead-o), not part of the calling convention.

---

If it had needed to `sub $16, %rsp` / `mov`-store / `leave`, e.g. if you'd compiled with `-mno-red-zone`, then yes it could have been an optimization to do that spill with `push %rdi`.  But [existing compilers don't do that optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49485395/what-c-c-compiler-can-use-push-pop-instructions-for-creating-local-variables) for initializing + creating locals.

`push %rdi` in `worship` would have required the compiler to use `leave` instead of just `pop %rbp`, which is slightly more expensive.  And it would only align the stack to RSP%16 == 8 after `push %rbp` aligned it to RSP%16 == 0; compilers prefer to keep the stack aligned by 16 even when they're not making further function calls.

**And of course if you'd just enabled optimization,** `worship` would just be `xor %eax,%eax` / `ret`, not wasting instructions putting the register arg anywhere.

---

**Footnote 1**: `-Oz` (favour code-size without caring about speed) might use 3-byte `push imm8` / `pop rdi` instead of 5-byte `mov edi, imm32` to materialize a value in a register if it was in the -128..+127 range.  But 666 isn't, so `mov` is also the smallest way to set a register to that value without any pre-existing known register values near that. ([Code golf x86-64 machine code tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132981/tips-for-golfing-in-x86-x64-machine-code/132985#132985)).

Answer (score 0):

Compilers like GCC are written by people who *very* carefully consider how to make often used code snippets (like function call/return) as efficient as possible. Sure, their solutions target the general case, in special cases there might be better options.

Comment: This is un-optimized code.  `mov` to the red-zone *is* the most efficient way to spill the incoming register arg if you're going to do that at all, but if you tell the compiler to make any effort to make efficient code, `worship()` will compile to `xor %eax,%eax` / `ret`.