# Why does the x86-64 System V calling convention pass args in registers instead of just the stack?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

Why is it that 32-bit C pushes all function arguments straight onto the stack while 64-bit C puts the first 6 arguments into registers and the rest on the stack?

So the 32-bit stack would look like:

```
...
arg2
arg1
return address
old %rbp
```

While the 64-bit stack would look like:

```
...
arg8
arg7
return address
old %rbp
arg6
arg5
arg4
arg3
arg2
arg1
```

So why does 64-bit C do this? Isn't it much easier to just push everything to the stack instead of put the first 6 arguments in registers just to move them onto the stack in the function prologue?

Comment: It's not required to move them to the stack in the prologue or at all.

Comment: @Jester I was looking at some code that gcc generated and that's what it always did. I was just wondering why it was doing this. And my main question is why the args aren't just pushed straight onto the stack anymore.

Comment: @AlSmith Did you compile with optimizations on, e.g. using `-O3`

Comment: I did not @user3386109

Comment: Then be aware that with optimizations off, the compiler does a lot of unnecessary stuff, some of which makes life easier for the debugger.

Comment: I want to remove C from this question as this has nothing to do with C...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> instead of put the first 6 arguments in registers just to move them onto the stack in the function prologue?

> I was looking at some code that gcc generated and that's what it always did.

**Then you forgot to enable optimization**.  `gcc -O0` [spills everything to memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53366394/why-does-clang-produce-inefficient-asm-with-o0-for-this-simple-floating-point) so you can modify them with a debugger while single-stepping.  That's obviously horrible for performance, so compilers don't do that unless you force them to by compiling with `-O0`.

x86-64 System V allows `int add(int x, int y) { return x+y; }` to compile to
`lea eax, [rdi + rsi]` / `ret`, which is what compilers actually do as you can see on [the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/rG7VTF).

Stack-args calling conventions are slow and obsolete.  RISC machines have been using register-args calling conventions since before x86-64 existed, and on OSes that still care about 32-bit x86 (i.e. Windows), there are better calling conventions like `__vectorcall` that pass the first 2 integer args in registers.

i386 System V hasn't been replaced because people mostly don't care as much about 32-bit performance on other OSes; we just use 64-bit code with the nicely-designed x86-64 System V calling convention.

For more about the tradeoff between register args and call-preserved vs. call-clobbered registers in calling convention design, see [Why not store function parameters in XMM vector registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33707228/why-not-store-function-parameters-in-float-registers), and also [Why does Windows64 use a different calling convention from all other OSes on x86-64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429398/why-does-windows64-use-a-different-calling-convention-from-all-other-oses-on-x86/35619528#35619528).

Comment: People cared enough to create https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI but it doesn't seem to have gained much traction.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: Yeah, it's too bad it hasn't caught on more.  32-bit pointers can be really cool for lockless programming on a 64-bit ISA: you can very efficiently CAS a pointer+counter without any non-portable hacks to fight against C++11's design where atomic access to part of a larger object is not supported.  But I didn't mention it separately because it's a flavour of the x86-64 SysV ABI, and is documented [in a chapter of the same PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18133812), not even in a separate document.  Its calling convention is identical; only some type sizes change.